# How to fix "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number" appearing only in Chrome?

Tags: django, google-chrome, gunicorn, chromium

I am trying to run a Django site, using Gunicorn (with docker compose). Everything works as expected in Firefox, but Chrome reports the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number" for random .js scripts. If I reload the page, scripts are loaded without any errors.

So, at first I had a similar issue, since Chrome was randomly failing to load scripts. I solved this by changing the port in Gunicorn from 8080 to 80. However, once I did that, the scripts started loading but also started throwing the Unexpected number error.

I have tested it on both Chromium (Ubuntu 18) and Google Chrome (Windows), running the web site locally and from a server.

Also, I've noticed the following:

1) files which throw errors are rarely the same, so in one window script example1.js may work, and example2.js throws the error, and in another window example3.js throws an error and the rest work.

2) if I reload the page, no .js file throws an error.

3) every error indicates that the problem is in line 5, like this: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number               jquery-3.2.1.min.js:5".

Would greatly appreciate any advise on how to tackle this.

Comment: Open the Chrome Developer Tools and click on the error info in the console to see what code Chrome actually received. It ~sounds~ like there's a network problem where Chrome isn't actually getting the data you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Eric. I've managed to solve the issue, and you were right. Once I added nginx to the configuration I have no issues with loading static files. I'm not really sure where the issue exactly was, but this sorted it out.